# How to insert a list into mysql that needs to go into 1 column using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list or it can be a tuple what ever will work. The list are all variables and will be numbers.

```
    varlist = [temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6]
```

I then use this code to insert it into the database.

```
    sql2 = "INSERT INTO sensor_data Values ({0})".format(varlist)
    cursor.execute(sql2)
```

Here is the variable sql2 printed out.

```
    INSERT INTO sensor_data Values ((76.7, 76.3, 76.2, 76.3, 76.2, 76.2))
```

I have tried all kinds of different ideas but keep getting errors. Here is the one I get using the terminal in a python script.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "GetSensorDataHistory.py", line 188, in <module>
      cursor.execute(sql2)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
      self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
      raise errorclass, errorvalue
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
```

I need all of the list in 1 table column and ideally would love it to be formatted like this.

```
    +-------------------------------+
    | sensor_data                   |
    +-------------------------------+
    | 76.7|76.3|76.2|76.3|76.2|76.2 |
    +-------------------------------+
```

Then I can use perl or php to split on the pipe or | and get my results on a select when I need it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the list or tuple to string and then insert into the table

```
list_str = '|'.join(str(item) for item in varlist)

sql2 = "INSERT INTO sensor_data Values ('{0}')".format(list_str)
```

Comment: if the values in varlist are from users, I would use the semi-prepared statements, like so `cursor.execute(sql3, tuple(varlist))` where `sql3 = 'INSERT INTO sensor_data Values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'`. This would be to prevent sql injection, but I would simply always use those prepared statements as a habit.

Comment: @Matthias I will not have any users from the web so I should be okay.

Comment: `code`while True:
   temp1 = tempRead1()
   temp2 = tempRead2()
   temp3 = tempRead3()
   temp4 = tempRead4()
   temp5 = tempRead5()
   temp6 = tempRead6()
   sensor_data = "sensor_data"
   # Data Insert into the table
   varlist = (temp1,temp2,temp3,temp4,temp5,temp6)
   list_str = '|'.join(str(item) for item in varlist)
   sql2 = "INSERT INTO sensor_data Values ({0})".format(list_str)
   print "SQL string is : " + sql2
   try:
      cursor.execute(sql2)
      # Commit your changes in the database
      db.commit()
   except MySQLdb.Error as e:
      db.rollback()
   break  `code`

Comment: @Termi That is the code I have above but hard to read.  Is there a better way to display this? It works on the last entry and I do not get the full string. I have no errors so I can't see why it is putting in only 1 value instead of the full string. Does the pipe have anything to do with it? I can use something better if it is?

Comment: @Termi I had to change the ({0}) to ('{0}')  and that did it. Thank you!

Comment: @Matthias I don't think there is any difference between the two . anyway the inputs are numbers so no problem

Comment: @joeb oh yeah the string should be in quotes. thanks

Comment: @Termi `string.format` is a built-in python method, so I see no reason it should do any preparing of statements by default. I assume it works like [the do not do this](http://bobby-tables.com/python.html). I could be wrong of course, but surprisingly this seems hard to find on the web. But all the "python prevent sql injection" sites say to do it like I showed above. But like you said, since it's not text input from the user, both ways are perfectly fine.